# Prepend String Using CONCAT/CONCAT_WS with STRING_AGG results if STRING_AGG is NOT Empty or NULL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, object, concatenation, jsonb

I have JSONB data that is stored in the data column like so:

```
...
"dealers": [
    { "dealership":"LHM"},
    { "dealership”:"Camp"},
    { "dealership":"HMA"}
  ],

"cars": [
    { "name":"Ford"},
    { "name":"BMW" },
    { "name":"Fiat"}
  ],
...
```

There are several more attributes which store several more arrays of objects, but for the sake of simplifying my question I only wanted to mention these two.

Firstly, I wanted to see if I could collect all of the name attributes from each object into one field.  I found the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243817/concatenate-string-values-of-objects-in-a-postgresql-json-array) and accepted answer which got me to my initial goal doing something similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    id
  , STRING_AGG(car->>'name', ', ')
FROM
  autos,
  json_array_elements(autos.data->'cars') as car
GROUP BY 1
```

This results in a single field that looks like this:

```
Ford, BMW, Fiat
```

My end goal now is to be able to concatenate all of the other STRING_AGG object attributes from MULTIPLE arrays of objects into one field prepended with a brief description of each, but ONLY if the result of STRING_AGG is NOT EMPTY and NOT NULL (Most important in my case is NOT EMPTY ('').  For example, it should look like this:

```
...//Cars: Ford, BMW, Fiat //Dealerships: LMH, Camp, HMA //... // etc.
```

I have tried to use CONCAT and CONCAT_WS, and tried utilizing NULLIF but am not sure how to achieve what I am looking for. Particularly, if it is possible to prepend a description string to each STRING_AGG result.  Can you assist?

UPDATE: I was able to figure out how to do this with case statements inside of a CONCAT, but I am now wondering if that is a good way to do this or if this can be done in a similar way to S-Man’s given answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click: step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a62343a6db28562cf8458d439e274fc1)

```
WITH autos AS (
    SELECT '{"cars": [{"name": "BMW", "year": 1991}, {"name": "Ford", "model": "Mustang"}, {"name": "Fiat"}, {"name": "VW", "model": "Golf", "year": 2000}, {"name": "VW", "model": ""}]}'::jsonb as data
)
SELECT 
    'Cars: ' || STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'name', ''), ',') || ' // '
    'Years: ' || STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'year', ''), ',') || ' // '
    'Models: ' || STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'model', ''), ',')
FROM autos,
    jsonb_array_elements(data->'cars') as car
```

Using this data set:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "name": "BMW",
            "year": 1991
        },
        {
            "name": "Ford",
            "model": "Mustang"
        },
        {
            "name": "Fiat"
        },
        {
            "name": "VW",
            "year": 2000,
            "model": "Golf"
        },
        {
            "name": "VW",
            "model": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see: no `model` (`== null`) for the `BMW`, no `year` for the `Ford`, no data at all for the `Fiat`, all attributes at the `VW Golf`, an empty `model` for the second `VW`.

First get a table for all data:

```
SELECT 
    car ->> 'name' as name,
    car ->> 'year' as year,
    car ->> 'model' as model
FROM autos,
    jsonb_array_elements(data->'cars') as car
```

You already used the `jsonb_array_elements()` function, which expands a JSON array. The `->>` operator gives the value of the attributes (in this case of each array element) as `text`.

Now, you could normalize the empty values (`model` of the second `VW`, in this case) to `NULL` using `NULLIF()`. You could make a value to `NULL` if it is empty:

```
NULLIF(myvalue, '')
```

This would lead you to:

```
SELECT 
    NULLIF(car ->> 'name', '') as name,
    NULLIF(car ->> 'year', '') as year,
    NULLIF(car ->> 'model', '') as model
FROM autos,
    jsonb_array_elements(data->'cars') as car
```

Now you have no empty values anymore, but many `NULL` values.

Now, you could use `STRING_AGG()` to aggregate all values as you expect. The clue is, `STRING_AGG()` automatically ignores `NULL` values, so you don't need to hesitate.

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'name', ''), ',') as names,
    STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'year', ''), ',') as years,
    STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'model', ''), ',') as models
FROM autos,
    jsonb_array_elements(data->'cars') as car
```

Now, you only have three columns and one row. Every value is aggregated into on string.

Finally you want to chain them into one string. For this you could use `CONCAT()` or the operator `||`:

```
SELECT 
    'Cars: ' || STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'name', ''), ',') || ' // '
    'Years: ' || STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'year', ''), ',') || ' // '
    'Models: ' || STRING_AGG(NULLIF(car ->> 'model', ''), ',')
FROM autos,
    jsonb_array_elements(data->'cars') as car
```

---

**Edit:**

Clarified data:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "name": "BMW"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ford"
        },
        {
            "name": "Fiat"
        }
    ],
    "dealers": [
        {
            "dealership": "LHM"
        },
        {
            "dealership": "Camp"
        },
        {
            "dealership": "HMA"
        }
    ]
}
```

Click: [demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0b18dd7c6d627d63d8b9a42a0f824450)

```
SELECT
    'Cars: ' || s1.names || ' // Dealers: ' || s2.dealerships
FROM
    autos, 
    LATERAL (SELECT string_agg(c ->> 'name', ',') as names FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'cars') as c) s1,
    LATERAL (SELECT string_agg(d ->> 'dealership', ',') as dealerships FROM jsonb_array_elements(data->'dealers') as d) s2
```

In that case, you have to expand and aggregate your arrays before joining. Please add the `NULLIF()` function at the relevant columns as done above.

Comment: I did end up figuring this out today, and greatly appreciate your help.  I think I should have explained my question a bit better though.  Your way is really handy, but what if you have multiple arrays of objects that you are wanting to get concatenated into a single field, similar to how you have done with your chaining method in your answer?  Is that doable in a similar way?

Comment: Please provide an example (for this  please edit your question)

Comment: no problem. I updated my question. Is that more clear, or are you needing additional clarity/detail?

Comment: In that case you have to expand and merge the arrays before joining. According to https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/161799 this can be done this way: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0b18dd7c6d627d63d8b9a42a0f824450; Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to work this out.  I am marking your answer as correct.  I ended up doing something similar to what you told me about but a little bit different.  Ultimately, your answer and follow up suggestion helped! Thank you.